# Why is strict mode's activator 'use strict' a string?

Tags: javascript, strict

Not to be confused with wanting to know how use strict works, but why is strict mode activated with `'use strict';` or `"use strict";` as opposed to an expression like `use strict;`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`use strict;` would throw an error in JS engines that did not support strict mode.

Using a string is backwards compatible.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is simple. As we know, ECMAScript a.k.a javascript is not standarized until now. So why string? It's because all browsers agree to use `'use strict'` as more preferable than `use strict`. It also to prevent error on older browser which is not support strict mode.